# C++ - Implementação de classe statica cpp

Tags: c++

Ola!
eu estava tentando implementar uma classe Estatica mas tive o seguinte erro:
"undefined reference to matematica::cod" mas a variavel cod está no .h
segue o código abaixo da classe .h e cpp;

```
#ifndef MATEMATICA_H
#define MATEMATICA_H


class matematica
{
  public:
    static int getCod();
    static void setCod(int);

  protected:

  private:
    static int cod;

};

#endif // MATEMATICA_H
```

CLASSE CPP:

```
#include "matematica.h"


void matematica::setCod(int c)
{
   matematica::cod = c;
}
```

não sei oque fazer.

Comment: E por que faria isto?

Comment: estou aprendendo a mexer com classe static. para conhecer um pouco sobre a implementação dela. mas não faço ideia do porque esse erro está acontecendo

Comment: A questão é que quase sempre uma classe estática é um erro em C++. Na forma apresentada parece ser totalmente um erro, porque parece que deveria ser uma classe normal. Se tentar fazer uma classe estática onde deveria ser uma normal estará aprendendo errado. Por isso nem tem o conceito de classe estática em C++, você pode ter membros estáticos, mas não a classe toda, e se todos são estáticos tem grande chance que não precisava de uma classe.

Comment: Mineiro pode dar um exemplo de como usar corretamente? Sempre tive dúvidas

Comment: Não por duas razões, não é nosso objetivo do SOpt dar exemplos, responder perguntas abertas onde qualquer resposta pode ser certa ou errada. Mas principalmente porque eu nunca usaria uma classe "estática", qualquer uma é errada pra mim. Classe estática é um conceito interessante em linguagens como Java ou C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arquivo header você está apenas declarando a variável estática. Em outras palavras você está apenas dando um nome e um tipo. A variável não é "criada". Em algum outro lugar (por exemplo, no arquivo .cpp correspondente) você precisa definir a variável, isto é, efetivamente criá-la.

Basta pensar o seguinte: se a varíável não fosse uma variável estática ela também não existiria até que uma instância da classe fosse criada.

TLDR;

No arquivo .cpp correspondente faça:

`int matematica::cod = 0;`